# Issues installing a python wrapper for a C program on Linux Subsystem for Windows

Tags: python, c, cython, wrapper, bioinformatics

I am trying to use a new bioinformatics program written in C named 'Giggle'. They have included a python wrapper. Since I am on Windows 10 most of the bioinformatics stuff is only available for Linux, I am using the Linux subssystem with python 2 installed. The installation for the wrapper are as follows:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/brentp/python-giggle
cd python-giggle
python setup.py test
python setup.py install
```

When running the `setup.py test` I encountered all sorts of dependencies of which I had never heard like libbz2 and liblzma. Installation of these dependencies worked fine with `sudo apt-get install` but now upon running the test I get a long list of warnings like this one:

```
    lib/htslib/hfile_libcurl.c:187:13: warning: function declaration isn’t a 
        prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
        static void libcurl_exit()
```

These are all for different .h and .c files. The list ends with several errors:

```
    lib/htslib/hfile_s3.c:70:2: error: #error No HMAC() routine found by configure
 #error No HMAC() routine found by configure
  ^
lib/htslib/hfile_s3.c: In function ‘s3_rewrite’:
lib/htslib/hfile_s3.c:335:30: error: ‘DIGEST_BUFSIZ’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         unsigned char digest[DIGEST_BUFSIZ];
                              ^
lib/htslib/hfile_s3.c:335:30: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
lib/htslib/hfile_s3.c:336:29: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘s3_sign’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         size_t digest_len = s3_sign(digest, &secret, &message);
                             ^
lib/htslib/hfile_s3.c:335:23: warning: unused variable ‘digest’ [-Wunused-variable]
         unsigned char digest[DIGEST_BUFSIZ];
                       ^
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I am kind of lost on this and googling the errors has not made me any wiser. I feel like it is a 'you are still using windows' kind of problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Based on the first warning: is it possible you are applying 21st century C compiler defaults to 20th century code? (Trying not to be mean and say "19th century" here...)

Comment: How would I find out? :)

Comment: The functions `static void libcurl_exit()`, `static void process_messages()`, and `static int wait_perform()` (and probably more) are defined in an old-fashioned way. The current 'PC' way is to have `..(void)` as their argument, not *nothing*. I think I saw a `-Werror` somewhere in one of the makefiles. It may or may not be enough to remove that – if not, contact the authors.

Comment: I don't think the warnings are particularly important to why it's failing. Looking at `hfile_s3.c`, I think you need either CommonCrypto or OpenSSL. I think CommonCrypto is Mac only so you should look at installing OpenSSL headers.

Comment: Thanks, installing OpenSSL did the trick!